# How to Purchase Additional Drive Storage with Legacy GSuite

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace

My group uses a Legacy Free Addition of G Suite (which continues to be offered indefinitely, whether used by a single person, a couple people, a family, a non-profit, or any other group).

We purchased additional storage in Google Drive for one of our users. We now want to purchase addition storage for a second user. However, we are unable to do so using the same exact credit card. We receive the following error which links to [this page](https://support.google.com/pay/answer/7644087) which offers nothing that has not already been attempted:

*"Your transaction cannot be completed. Learn More."*

[image]

The card is correctly/identically entered. There is no issue at the bank. Within Super Admin, all of the necessary features are enabled (Individual Storage, Google Play/Payments, etc.).

Again, we just purchased for one user in the group. We now want to purchase for a second user with the same payment method, but cannot do so. We have also tried 2 other credit cards, both of which are valid, working credit cards. One is Mastercard, one is Amex, one is Visa.

I discovered [one other post about this](https://support.google.com/a/thread/22012755), but in my case, we can further verify that 1) that we in fact did pay for storage for another user and 2) the same card will not work nor will other cards.

How do we purchase additional storage in Google Drive for this second user in our organization?

---

**Update 7/17/2021**

According to the information [here](https://support.google.com/a/thread/117464507/unable-to-purchase-drive-storage?hl=en), Google's support doc page does not state that such legacy accounts are supported.

Unfortunately, the support doc page that is referenced doesn't seem to be a reliable source for verification, because it contained the same statement as far back as October 2019 (likely earlier), yet we were still able to add storage just 2 weeks ago. That, combined with the fact that the process can be proceeded through all the way up to the point of transaction (as opposed to the feature not being show or supported) would indicate that there is a different primary factor at work.

[image]

In all seriousness, it seems that the current state is: it might be unsupported, but it might be supported for some organizations, or maybe just some users within some groups, and in those cases, maybe only once, but maybe more than once if done close together, and maybe only for certain storage options.

I look forward to someone being able to provide further insight here as to how this feature of additional storage is handled, and whether additional storage can be added to such legacy accounts and, if so, how it was achieved (as we seemed to have done).

References:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20201111221857/https://support.google.com/a/answer/177064
- https://web.archive.org/web/20191029134332/https://support.google.com/a/answer/177064

Comment: Are you credit cards of the same type (Visa, Master Card, American Express) ? Have you already reviewed if there are other payment methods available for you? Some accounts could use Google Pay , Google Play Cards,  Bank transfer, Paypal.... A

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because according to https://apps.google.com/supportwidget/articlehome?hl=en "For businesses, the G Suite legacy free edition will no longer be available after June 27, 2022." Individuals and other cases, in case of having a similar question, better to ask a new question.

Comment: The question is valid and will remain valid as long as any users are still on the Legacy GSuite, which continues to be offered indefinitely. The question does now not refer to business in any way, and can refer to any individual or group on a custom domain, whether it's 1 person, 2 people, a family, a non-profit, or any other group.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify that directly into the question body.

Comment: @Rubén : Alright, edited.

Answer (score -2):

According to the Google Workspace Admin Help, besides credit cards there are other payment options:

- Debit card
- Bank transfer
- Wire transfer
- Check

But they might not be available for all. See the following official help articles for details:

- [Payment options for your Google service](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1230192?hl=en&ref_topic=2781720)
- [Payment options in my country](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2380700?hl=en)