# Additional Drive Storage with free G Suite legacy edition for personal use

Tags: g-suite-administrator, g-suite-business

How do we purchase additional storage in Google Drive for G Suite Legacy (For Personal Use) Users?

Background:

- A thread was opened called "**How to Purchase Additional Drive Storage with Legacy GSuite**" and closed because it related to businesses and now G Suite Legacy is only available for Personal Use.
- This thread has been created to track **G Suite Legacy "For Personal Use"** **how to get additional drive storage**, which Google has mentioned would be in the pipeline.

Timeline:

- Early adopters of Google Apps back in 2008 could sign up for a free unlimited user account.
- May 2011 this was then restricted to less users for many.
- 2016 it was renamed to Google Apps and later became G Suite Legacy.
- Early 2022 Google announced that G Suite Legacy would be end of life and users would have to migrate to a pay plan Workspace Business Edition.
- 9th April 2020 Update

> A no-cost option will be available for all customers who do not want
> to use Gmail with their custom domain (for example,
> your-name@example.com), or the ability to manage multiple users.
> Customers who choose this option will retain access to the no-cost
> version of Google Workspace services such as Google Drive and Google
> Meet, and additional Google services such as Google Search, Google
> Maps, and YouTube. You will also retain access to paid content such as
> movies purchased in the Google Play Store. You'll see a message about
> the waiting list in your Google Admin console in the coming weeks. If
> you want the no cost option, you need to join this waiting list in the
> Google Admin console before June 1, 2022, so your account is not
> automatically upgraded to Google Workspace. Those on the waiting list
> will remain on the G Suite legacy free edition until the no-cost
> option is available. Once the no-cost option is available, we’ll be in
> touch with more details on what will happen to your account. You will
> have 60 days to evaluate the no-cost option or choose Google Workspace
> before any changes are made to your account. If you change your mind
> after you join the waiting list for the no-cost option, you’ll still
> be able to upgrade to Google Workspace at any time.

Ref: https://9to5google.com/2022/04/05/g-suite-legacy-delay/

***May 2022 After a backlash and some legal action Google announced that G Suite legacy edition could continue but only for "Personal Use" not Business Use.***

**G Suite Legacy for Personal Use**
Ref: https://apps.google.com/supportwidget/articlehome?hl=en&article_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.google.com%2Fa%2Fanswer%2F60217%3Fhl%3Den&assistant_event=welcome&assistant_id=!EeLdngiT4qrN8SULewzJ1s8nfrtSpqO4&product_context=60217&product_name=UnuFlow&trigger_context=a

**Business Thread**
Ref: [How to Purchase Additional Drive Storage with Legacy GSuite](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/155852/how-to-purchase-additional-drive-storage-with-legacy-gsuite?noredirect=1)

**More Storage**
Ref: https://apps.google.com/supportwidget/articlehome?article_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.google.com%2Fa%2Fanswer%2F12005619&assistant_id=generic-unu&product_context=12005619&product_name=UnuFlow&trigger_context=a

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The Other Thread has been re-opened which covers this but was closed 
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/155852/how-to-purchase-additional-drive-storage-with-legacy-gsuite?noredirect=1#comment157723_155852